Potential leaking window. How do I fix it?
Just noticed a big water stain on the top part of the blinds and water stains on the bottom left corner of the window casing after heavy rain. During a recent storm with blowing rain, the bottom left corner was wet to the touch and there seemed to be water trailing down from the top somewhere based on the drip marks found on the window itself, but no idea where the water could be coming from and whether it’s a single source or multiple sources.
Images 1–5 are from the heavy rain, 6–9 are from recent blowing rain, and I also included a video of the window exterior in case it helps identify the problem.
https://imgur.com/a/AwreOgQ
The adjacent window about 2-3ft away window also has a small water stain on the bottom right corner but the wall in between both windows is reading very low moisture on the moisture meter (0.8–1%). The casing is close to the ceiling as well and the ceiling is reading 0.8%.
The bottom left corner of the casing went as high as 5% when it was raining outside. A few days out from the rain, the top left corner of the window casing is currently reading 3% and the bottom left corner of the casing is reading 4.2%.  The wall directly beneath the corner is now reading 4% which is a whole percent down from yesterday’s 5% reading. The bottom casing of other windows on the floor read about 2–3% on the meter and the wall surrounding it is about 1–2%. The back of the meter says anything under 8% is still considered “dry” so is this a cause for concern?
Looking for advice on what could be the cause, how to fix it, or what type of professional I should call to take a look at it.

Those are water stains, and water is getting in somehow. It's impossible to determine the cause of the leak without inspecting the window in person, but these are the most likely culprits, in order of how likely:

Window flashing not installed properly or broken.
Rook leak.
Siding and/or water barrier (tar paper, house wrap) broken.
Pipe leaking upstairs.

The difficulty with finding leaks is that water travels, so the leak could be in another part of the house and traveling, for example, through a skylight, then to a rafter, then to the wall cavity, then to the window, then coming out in the window sill, where you are seeing it.
A good handyman should be able to trace the leak.

Nothing a tube of Silicone can not fix.
Just ask the friendly people at the hardware store for UV resistant window silicone.
Go outside and apply silicone all around where the window meets the wall

It's silicone...
